# bitbake can't build cppzmq when it's included in an image

Tags: cross-compiling, zeromq, yocto, bitbake

I'm building a yocto project which uses `cppzmq` (http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/123508/)

The strange thing is that when I build it directly
`bitbake cppzmq`
it builds successfully.

But when I include it in my image
`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " cppzmq"`
there is an error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'cppzmq' (but /home/ccccc/yocto-tegra/meta-eee/recipes-images/images/image-eee.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'cppzmq' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['cppzmq']
ERROR: Required build target 'image-eee' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['image-eee', 'cppzmq']
```

If I run `bitbake-layers show-recipes cppz*`, it shows:

```
Parsing of 2234 .bb files complete (2233 cached, 1 parsed). 3398 targets, 141 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
=== Matching recipes: ===
cppzmq:
  meta-oe              4.6.0
```

it's clearly included.

I don't know why cppzmq can't build when it's included in an image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to distinguish between the recipe name `cppzmq` and the provided packages of the recipe. A single recipe can provide several packages (`<recipename>`, `<recipename>-dev`, `<recipename>-staticdev` etc.).

With `IMAGE_INSTALL` you define which **packages** are included in the image.

Looking at the [cppzmq recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-connectivity/zeromq/cppzmq_git.bb?h=dunfell) you can see that it only provides `PACKAGES = "${PN}-dev"`.

Hence you should use `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " cppzmq-dev"`